# Build failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[At the time of release build  getting error in react native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfKiA.png)

Comment: seems like the spacing in between is causing an issue. would it help if it was removed and recompile again?

Comment: Please add some code and context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario I think you haven't made a js bundle so please make a bundle first by using command from your project root folder

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

After that move in to your project's android directory using `cd android`

Before make release build make sure to clean your gradle using `./gradlew clean`

And finally run this command `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

**I have posted a full answer on this issue on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183395/getting-error-while-creating-release-apk-from-react-native-with-gradlew-assemble/60184843#60184843)**