# getting error while creating release apk from react native with gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: android, react-native

i want to release the apk but im getting error -file already exists, mkdir 'D:\mobile'.its generating file nameed mobile in the d drive. after deleting the file , executing gradlew assembleRelease again creating this file and throwing error.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>   Loading dependency graph, done.
>   info Writing bundle output to:, D:\mobile
>   info Writing sourcemap output to:, D:\mobile
>   info Done writing bundle output
>   info Done writing sourcemap output
>   info Copying 24 asset files
>   error EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\mobile'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>   Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\mobile'
>
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your scenario I think you haven't made a js bundle so please make a bundle first by using command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

After that move in to your project's android directory using `cd android`

Before make release build make sure to clean your gradle using  `./gradlew clean`

And finally run this command  `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Comment: can u tel me at what folder this react-native bundle need to run android folder or project folder?for cmd command running

Comment: @krishnamohan you need to run bundle code from the project root folder

Comment: I got invalid expression error `Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/:`

nvm. got to fix it. :)